# query in codeigniter: get where or

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

how can I select multiple or in codeigniter?

for exmaple, `select * from bla where id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3?`

If I use this:

```
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->where('title', $title);
$this->db->where('status', $status);
```

it is with AND...

Comment: Please search this site and/or refer to [the manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html) before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `where_in` method as a shortcut to multiple or-statements for the same column:

```
$available_ids = [1, 2, 3];

$this->db->where_in('id', $available_ids);
// WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

If you were looking to check multiple columns (the name is 'Adam' or the title is 'Grand Poobah' or the status is 'Active'), you can use the `or_where` method instead:

```
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->or_where('title', $title);
$this->db->or_where('status', $status); 
// WHERE name = 'Adam' OR title = 'Grand Poobah' OR status = 'Active'
```

To put it all together, you'd

```
$available_ids = [1, 2, 3];

$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('bla')->where_in('id', $available_ids)->get();
// SELECT * FROM bla WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

[CodeIgniter v3 Reference](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)
[CodeIgniter v2 Reference](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Comment: but how you select the table in the first option?

Comment: You'd use the `$this->db->from($table_name)` method; I've updated my answer to put everything together.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
$array = array(
    'name' => $name, 
    'title' => $title, 
    'status' => $status
);
$this->db->where($array);
```

> > Add all data to an array. Then pass the array to where clause.