# Codeigniter where and where db query with an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table of users with the following data:

```
id     first_name

10     user one
21     user two
39     user 3
```

So I want to fetch all users with specific `id`s, like when I pass `id` of 10 and 21 I want to retrieve first 2 users.

So in Codeigniter I have a functions `getUsersByIds` in my model like:

```
class UsersModel extends CI_Model{

    public function getUsersByIds($ids){  
        $data = [];
        foreach($ids as item){
            $this->db->where('user_id',(int)$item);
        }
        $rs = $this->db->get('users');
        return $rs->result_array();
    }
}
```

Now whenever I try calling the above model in my controller via:

```
$this->load->model('UsersModel');
var_dump($this->UsersModel->getUsersByIds([10,21])) //this is null
```

The above `var_dump` is `null`. I suspect the issue occurs on the foreach loop.  Is there a way I can do `where` and `where in` Codeigniter with dynamic data like the above?

Comment: You can simply use where_in method without foreach loop to get data for both single and multiple ids, you just need to send ids in an array.

Comment: typo? `$ids as item` should be `$ids as $item`, or was that just a code pasting error?

Comment: also look at https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#looking-for-specific-data section Associative array method (as pointed out by @Amir's comment above

Comment: @AmirHussain where_in method may not work in this case as it will check only the first number and return the results. Eg: with 10 and 21 it will only check for the first number but i want my search to ensure its both numbers before returning the result

Comment: @Vickel its just a pasting error.. Its not an issue on the code.

Comment: @Geoff sir `ids` come from controller from view to by which input tag?

Comment: @Geoff sir tell me??

Comment: @Geoff where_in will check all the possibilities and will return the matched data.

Comment: Have you tried to debug what happens? I would assume that you create some kind of `AND` concatenated query, and that would obviously not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [query in codeigniter: get where or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273114/query-in-codeigniter-get-where-or)

Answer (score 2):

Your case shouldn't really use the where method in the query builder. It should be using the where_in that was built exactly to be used with arrays.

So your model function should look like this:

```
class UsersModel extends CI_Model{

   public function getUsersByIds($ids){
      if (empty($ids) {
         return array();
      }  
      $this->db->where_in('user_id',$ids);
      $rs = $this->db->get('users')->result_array();
      return $rs;
   }
}
```